# ¿Hay alguna forma de pedir permiso a un navegador, con política de cookies estricta, para aceptar las cookies de mi app?

Tags: cookies, permisos, navegador-web, setcookie

Implementé una sesión con una cookie segura del servidor. Pero en la PC de mi empleador no está almacenada.

Logré reproducir este comportamiento negando las cookies en mi navegador. ¿Hay alguna forma, API, de solicitar permisos para que mi aplicación almacene cookies?

incluso mejor si pudieran proporcionar una forma de usarlo en nextjs, pero con la API de JavaScript podría funcionar.

No estoy hablando del consentimiento de cookies de protección de datos.

He leído la documentación para pedir permisos a través de manifest.json, pensé que los service workers podrían tener acceso a la API del navegador, pero no he podido implementar una prueba exitosa, ni siquiera una que pueda arrojar luz.

Comment: La aceptación de cookies requiere la conformidad formal del usuario, por lo que en principio, y aunque fuese una red local, tendrías que agregarle al inicio la verificación de si tiene cookies activadas, y también el aviso para su aceptación, como ves siempre en toda web. Es altamente probable que la PC de tu empleador las tenga bloqueadas a nivel navegador, por seguridad (no me extrañaría que haya otros bloqueos). Verifica eso primero, y ve el tema de la detección de cookies permitidas. A partir de alí podemos avanzar.

Comment: Ok gracias. Si, con navigator.cookiesEnabled se puede ver si están permitidas o no.
Mi intención era mostrar una pregunta y que al aceptar, se agregue automaticamente. Pero si te entendí bien... eso no se puede hacer